# How to populate two separate arrays from one comma-delimited list?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a comma delimited text file that contains 20 digits separated by commas. These numbers represent earned points and possible points for ten different assignments. We're to use these to calculate a final score for the course.

Normally, I'd iterate through the numbers, creating two sums, divide and be done with it. However, our assignment dictates that we load the list of numbers into two arrays.

so this:

```
10,10,20,20,30,35,40,50,45,50,45,50,50,50,20,20,45,90,85,85
```

becomes this:

```
int[10] earned   = {10,20,30,40,45,50,20,45,85};
int[10] possible = {10,20,35,50,50,50,20,90,85};
```

Right now, I'm using

```
for (x=0;x<10;x++)
{
     earned[x] = scores[x*2]
     poss  [x] = scores[(x*2)+1]
}
```

which gives me the results I want, but seems excessively clunky.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You could run x up to 20 in steps of two. That removes the obscure multiplication.

Comment: @usr: Then you wouldn't be able to do `earned[x]`.

Comment: @Guvante true. Wasn't a good idea.

Comment: You could do `earned[x/2]`, if you wanted to step up by two.

Comment: what you could do to make the code slightly more robust is load the whole list in to an array then use a foreach to loop through each section of this complete array  and then use an counter to determine how many times you have been through the loop, if the counter is odd then it goes in to the earned array or if it is even then it goes in to the scores array thus removing the multiplication and if the size of the list changes there is no need to amend the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should split each alternating item the list into the other two lists.

```
int[20] scores = {10,10,20,20,30,35,40,50,45,50,45,50,50,50,20,20,45,90,85,85};

int[10] earned;
int[10] possible;

int a = 0;
for(int x=0; x<10; x++)
{
    earned[x] = scores[a++];
    possible[x] = scores[a++];
}
```

Comment: You have two problems. x/y is often used to handle matrix math, which you aren't doing here. Also now if you flip the internal lines you get completely different results.

Comment: @Guvante I've amended my answer to avoid confusion with matrix mathmatics

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ here:

```
var arrays = csv.Split(',')
                .Select((v, index) => new {Value = int.Parse(v), Index = index})
                .GroupBy(g => g.Index % 2, 
                         g => g.Value, 
                         (key, values) => values.ToArray())
                .ToList();
```

and then

```
var earned = arrays[0];
var possible  = arrays[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the "magic" multiplications and illegible array index computations.

```
var earned = new List<int>();
var possible = new List<int>();
for (x=0; x<scores.Length; x += 2)
{
     earned.Add(scores[x + 0]);
     possible.Add(scores[x + 1]);
}
```

This has very little that would need a text comment. This is the gold standard for self-documenting code.

I initially thought the question was a C question because of all the incomprehensible indexing. It looked like pointer magic. It was too clever.

In my codebases I usually have an `AsChunked` extension available that splits a list into chunks of the given size.

```
var earned = new List<int>();
var possible = new List<int>();
foreach (var pair in scores.AsChunked(2)) {
     earned.Add(pair[0]);
     possible.Add(pair[1]);
}
```

Now the *meaning*  of the code is apparent. The magic is gone.

Even shorter:

```
var pairs = scores.AsChunked(2);
var earned = pairs.Select(x => x[0]).ToArray();
var possible = pairs.Select(x => x[1]).ToArray();
```

Comment: Since this is an assignment, the arrays might be a requirement.

Comment: @MAV then call `ToArray` at the end.

Comment: "*our assignment dictates that we load the list of numbers into two arrays*". I interpret this to mean that lists are banned from the beginning. But if this is a valid solution for OPs assignment, I say go for it.

Comment: @MAV I would not assume that right of the bat. Also, that makes it a crazy assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could do it like this:

```
int[] earned = new int[10];
int[] possible = new int[10];
int resultIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < scores.Count; i = i + 2)
{
    earned[resultIndex] = scores[i];
    possible[resultIndex] = scores[i + 1];
    resultIndex++;
}
```

You would have to be sure that an equal number of values are stored in `scores`.

Answer (score 0):

**I would leave your code as is.** You are technically expressing very directly what your intent is, every 2nd element goes into each array.

The only way to improve that solution is to comment why you are multiplying. But I would expect someone to quickly recognize the trick, or easily reproduce what it is doing. Here is an **excessive** example of how to comment it. I wouldn't recommend using this directly.

```
for (x=0;x<10;x++)
{
     //scores contains the elements inline one after the other
     earned[x] = scores[x*2]     //Get the even elements into earned
     poss  [x] = scores[(x*2)+1] //And the odd into poss
}
```

However if you really don't like the multiplication, you can track the scores index separately.

```
int i = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    earned[x] = scores[i++];
    poss  [x] = scores[i++];
}
```

But I would probably prefer your version since it does not depend on the order of the operations.

Comment: I think the double increment of `i` is hard to understand. State mutation is harder to follow than functional expressions.

Comment: @usr: I agree, there isn't really a "clean" way to do this, which is what I was trying to express.

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = grades.Select((x, i) => new {x,i}).ToLookup(y=>y.i%2, y=>y.x)
int[] earned = res[0].ToArray();
int[] possible = res[1].ToArray();
```

This will group all grades into two buckets based on index, then you can just do `ToArray` if you need result in array form.

Answer (score -1):

here is an example of my comment so you do not need to change the code regardless of the list size:

```
ArrayList Test = new ArrayList { "10,10,20,20,30,35,40,50,45,50,45,50,50,50,20,20,45,90,85,85" };

        int[] earned = new int[Test.Count / 2];
        int[] Score = new int[Test.Count / 2];

    int Counter = 1; // start at one so earned is the first array entered in to
    foreach (string TestRow in Test)
    {
        if (Counter % 2 != 0) // is the counter even
        {
            int nextNumber = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < Score.Length; i++) // this gets the posistion for the next array entry
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Score[i])))
                {
                    nextNumber = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            Score[nextNumber] = Convert.ToInt32(TestRow);
        }
        else
        {
            int nextNumber = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < earned.Length; i++) // this gets the posistion for the next array entry
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(earned[i])))
                {
                    nextNumber = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            earned[nextNumber] = Convert.ToInt32(TestRow);
        }
        Counter++

    }
```

Comment: can I ask, why the down vote? This is an alternative solution to the problem which is exactly what the question was asking for

Comment: It's probably been down-voted because there are a number of errors in your answer. I've tried running your code and it doesn't work. Also converting an `int` to a string to test if it's `NullOrEmpty` is inefficient, especially so as your doing it in a `for` loop for the purpose of counting how many items you've already inserted into an `int` array. It would be far more efficient to keep track of the array position in a variable. I've created a [.NET Fiddle example](http://dotnetfiddle.net/2iMnL1) based off of your answer which works for a non-fixed length ArrayList.